How to get a VCD file from verilator
I have two verilog files: our.sv
module our(
        input clock,
        output reg [31:0] fn = 0);

   reg [31:0] fn1 = 1;

   always @(posedge clock) begin
      fn <= fn1;
      fn1 <= fn1 + fn;
   end

  initial begin
    $display("Fibonacci numbers:");
  end
endmodule

and our_tb.sv
module our_tb;

  // Inputs
  reg clock;

  // Outputs
  wire [31:0] fn;

  // Instantiate the module under test
  our uut (
    .clock(clock),
    .fn(fn)
  );

  // Clock generation
  always #5 clock <= ~clock; // Toggle clock every 5 time units

  initial begin
    // Initialize the clock
    clock = 0;

    // Wait for a few clock cycles
    repeat (20) @(posedge clock);

    // Print final message and finish the simulation
    $display("Simulation completed.");
    $finish;
  end

  // Monitor the output
  always @(posedge clock) begin
    $display("fn = %d", fn);
  end

endmodule

I want to get a vcd file from verilator so I try the following.
verilator -Wall --cc our_tb.sv --exe --main --timing --trace  --trace-structs  --binary --top our_tb
./obj_dir/Vour_tb

This only gets me the output of the testbench, but no VCD, how to get the VCD? I can't seem to find this info anywhere.

Unlike questasim or xsim, both verilator and iverilog need to be told to output a vcd, you do it like this.
   initial begin
      $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
      $dumpvars();
   end

in your main testbench, this is of course assuming you use --main to generate your c++ testbench.
